# Modify and run existing .NET assembly without saving to disk

Tags: .net, reflection, clr

Is there any way to modify methods in an existing .NET assembly, and execute the assembly without saving it to disk. I would like functionality similar to [`System.Reflection.Emit.MethodRental`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodrental.aspx) but the `Reflection.Emit` namespace only deals with dynamically created assemblies. There are many approaches that involve creating a new executable. or modifying an existing one, but I would like to avoid doing either of these.

I could use the CLR profiler's JIT compilation hooks to rewrite the method bodies as well, but would prefer an approach that could be done in C#. The use case is as part of a profiler that outputs program values at function entrance/exit.

Comment: THE CLR Profiler API would be the least effort, but that is still a lot of effort.

Comment: This magic just doesn't exist.  You already found the profiler angle, I don't know of anybody that actually made it work.  IL rewriting up front (AOP) is your solution.

Comment: In the end I modified the assembly by loading it into memory using the CCI Metadata re-writing library, having the program output as a MemoryStream and then calling Assembly.Load() on the resulting stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the modified binary contents you can use [`Assembly.Load(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx). However, you can't modify a *loaded* assembly - you'd have to handle the modifications separately.

You might also want to look at running this in a separate `AppDomain` if you are doing it repeatedly (if doing it just once, you probably don't need to).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Expressions trees" that comes with .net 3, they are also allows to create dynamic methods
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Also take a look at Mono.Cecil - this library allows to change code at runtime.